# Wrong path returned from MPV player using mp.get_property("path") spaces on Windows

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, lua, mpv

I have my video in the following locaton with spaces on Windows.

"c:\GoogleDrive\CMD Scripts_video\test.mp4"

MPV function in Lua script returns cut path with special characters ~1

video_path = mp.get_property("path")

"c:\GOOGLE~1\CMDSCR~1_video\test.mp4"

How can I get on Windows full path to use it as input for FFMPEG in my LUA script?

Thank you
Peter

Comment: Your 8.3-style path `c:\GOOGLE~1\CMDSCR~1_video\test.mp4` is absolutely valid and can be passed to any program.  Windows guarantees 8.3-style path is equivalent to "normal" path. There is no reason to convert it.

Comment: But FFMPEG throws following error with this 8.3 style path as input: (Paused) AV: 00:00:02 / 00:00:09 (28%) A-V:  0.000
[slicing] "C:\GoogleDrive\CMD Scripts_video\files\FFmpegAviSynthPlus64\ffmpeg.exe" -v warning -i "c:\GOOGLE~1\CMDSCR~1\test.mp4" out.avi
'C:\GoogleDrive\CMD' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 1):

8.3-style path is absolutely valid in Windows.
The error is raised by wrong quotation.

The correct way to invoke external command on Windows is the following:

```
""C:\GoogleDrive\CMD Scripts_video\files\FFmpegAviSynthPlus64\ffmpeg.exe" -v warning -i "c:\GOOGLE~1\CMDSCR~1\test.mp4" out.avi"
```

Please note quotes around argument, quotes around executable file path and quotes around the whole command (yes, Windows does need it).

```
os.execute([[""program" "arg1" "arg2""]])
```

Comment: Perfect. Working:)